# How Java know where is the dependency jar?

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I've made a simple maven project, here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>HelloWorld</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

It is a single file project, so this is the code:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I run `mvn package` and then 
`java -cp target/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.App` and everything works, i see "Hello World!" in my console.

So here's my question: how does Java know where is `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication` if i didn't specified the jar containing this class in classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. It's an annotation, and Java can run classes containing annotations that are not available in the classpath (by design).

This is what allows sharing classes between client and server, for example, that are annotated because the server needs the annotations, but which are useless at client-side.

Comment: So what's the point of this annotation? It's just a way to Spring identify this class later?

Comment: The point of this annotation is to be able to use Spring Boot. But your main method doesn't. It just use System.out.println(). That doesn't need (and doesn't use) anything from Spring Boot.

Comment: I don't understand very well but i think i will when i learn Spring. Anyway, you answered my question, thanks :)

Comment: What you have there is a basic Java class printing something in the console. And it happens to be annotated with a Spring annotation. This annotation is not in the classpath. But an annotation doesn't **do** anything. So it is just ignored by Java. If you started actually using Spring Boot in your code, and Spring Boot was not in the classpath, then you would have an error. An annotation is just metadata. This metadata can be used by frameworks (like Spring), which use reflection to inspect the presence and values of annotations. But you haven't started the framework yet.

Comment: How does java know that SpringBootApplication is an annotation if it is not in classpath? Let's say i remove @SpringBootApplication and stick with the import. Java doesn't care about unused imports? Even if they dont exists?

Comment: Imports don't exist in bytecode. They're just used at compile time to let you write `List` rather than `java.util.List`. The bytecode only contains fully qualified class names. And Java know it's an annotation because it's used as an annotation of the class in the bytecode. Just like you know that it's an annotation ecause it's used as an annotation in the source code.

Comment: But Java doesn't allow me to compile (javac) programs with imports that does not exists. So i need to provide the correct classpath when compiling, so Java knows that annotation really exists, but not when executing, am i correct?